# Converting number into time in same cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating schedule manager and I encountered this:

The user is prompted to type a number when he wants to start doing a certain task, for example number "13" should represent 13:00. But after he types this number, I need it to show as 13:00.

[image]]

In order to do this, I need to divide the number by 24 and then this number is convertible into the format I want (13:00). But I have no idea how to insert this number back into the same cell.

Is it possible, or is there another way to do this? It should also work if I type in half hours (13:30).

Comment: This will need to be done in a Worksheet_change event through the worksheet vba.

Comment: Another possibility might be to use a data validation rule. This could be used to create a drop-down of only valid data entry items.

Comment: Another solution is to enter the value in one place and convert/display it in another.

Comment: I can suggest you  Macro, will change the Decimal number into time according to 24 Hrs clock time in the same cell, just on one click. Please confirm are you comfortable with VBA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MAJOR EDIT**

Based on the feedback, this is a major rewrite of the original post.

Instead of converting the number in the same cell, you can convert the number during calculations.  With this approach, the user thinks that they are entering time in 24 hour format, but in reality it is an integer that gets converted to time.  Below is a sample.

[image: Timesheet sample]

Column H contains a description of what is in Column G for that row.

The key for the user is to enter the times in 24 hour format without the colon, which is noted in the banner at the top of the sheet.  If you format the time cells (rows 3, 4, and 6) with a custom format of `##":"00` they will look like they are displaying a standard time format.

Here are the cell content and formulas:

**G3:** Enter End Time here (24 hour format without the colon)
Value entered in example is `1645` but will display as `16:45`

**G4:** Enter Start Time here (24 hour format without the colon)
Value entered in example is `820` but will display as `8:20`

**G5:** `=TIME(INT(G3/100),MOD(G3,100),0)-TIME(INT(G4/100),MOD(G4,100),0)+IF(G3<=G4,1,0)` (8:25)

This subtracts the two times and corrects for negative time errors (`+IF(G3<=G4,1,0)`).

The TIME function takes input as hours, minutes, seconds `TIME(h,m,s)`.  Since G3 & G4 are integers, the hours are found by dividing by 100 (`INT(G3/100)` or the digits displayed to the left of the `:`), the minutes by taking the remainder of that division (`MOD(G4,100)` or the digits displayed to the right of the `:`), and the seconds are zero since we are dealing with whole minutes.

The result will be an actual time value and the cell should be formatted as time or custom (`h:mm`).

**G6:** Enter Break/Lunch Time here (24 hour format without the colon)
Value entered in example is `30` but will display as `:30`

**G7:** `=(G5-TIME(INT(G6/100),MOD(G6,100),0))*24` (7.92)

This converts G6 to a time format, as described above for cell G5, and subtracts the two times.

The difference is multiplied X24 to give an answer in decimal hours because my system required that type of entry.  If that is what you need, then format the cell as a number with 2 decimal places.

If you don't need decimal hours, then just leave our the `*24` from the formula and format the cell as time.

In my full sheet, Column G is repeated for each day of the week.  Hope this helps.

Comment: (1) Thanks for posting your formulas as text in addition to posting an image. (2) We prefer Excel formulas to have more explanation; compare to my answers [here](/q/1165378/150988#1167308 "Populate column with list based on matching criteria from other sheet"), [here](/q/1268388/150988#1268404 "Index-Match Excel") and [here](/q/1179620/150988#1180137 "Change a value and then update based on that new value").  In particular, I don’t understand how the formulas in `H6` and `H9` can use `G5` and `G8` as numbers, when they aren’t. (3) It’s an unfortunate coincidence that `G4`=`G5` in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, its different solution but correct solution, exactly what i needed. Though I dont understand the formula very much.

Comment: @Scott, the formulas in column H are for illustration purposes only and are just the text of the formulas in use in column G, e.g. the formula displayed in H5 is the formula that is used in G5.

Comment: The formula in G5 was the most difficult to get right, but it is checking the length of the values in G3 & G4 to first ensure that they don't have too many characters, then converting to a time each of those values, where the hours are the left two characters and the minutes are the right 2 characters.  At the end I add 1 to the value to prevent negative time if G3 < G4.

Comment: @Scott, edited post to address the issues you identified.

Comment: (0) Thanks for adding the explanations and changing the coincidentally equal values.  (1a) I figured that the formulas shown in Column `H` were the formulas used to compute the results shown in Column ``G``.  What I didn’t understand until now (because you didn’t explain it, and I didn’t feel like trying to decipher your formulas without any hints) was that, while Cells `G3`, `G4` and `G7` are plain numbers (integers ranging between 0 and 2359; e.g., 8 AM = 0800 = 8×60 is entered as 800 = 8×10×10) that are processed as text … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (you use `LEN`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` on them) and displayed with a funky format that makes them look like time values, Cells `G5` and `G8` are actually time values (i.e., they are actually numbers, probably between 0 and 1). This is exactly the sort of thing that an answer should explain. (1b) Since `G3` (and `G4`) are just numbers between 0 and 2359, why not just do ```TIME(INT(G3/100), MOD(G3,100), 0)```? …  (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2a) `MOD(G8,1)` is equivalent to `G8-INT(G8)` (but slightly shorter).  The difference in length and complexity becomes larger if you are referring to a complicated expression instead of a single cell.  (2b) Is there really a risk that `INT(G8)` could be non-zero?  `G8` is the difference of two times, so, worst case, it’s 23:59−00:00 = 0.999305556.  Or, if the times are in the wrong order, it’s between −1 and 0, and then you add 1, so it’s between 0 and 1.  (3) You can display 5 as `:05` just by formatting it as `##":"00`.

Comment: @Scott, I agree and have edited the post to reflect the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

*This Macro, will convert the Number into Time according to 24 Hrs clock time in the selected Cell/Cells.*

```
Sub NumberToTime()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iHours As Integer
    Dim iMins As Integer

    For Each rCell In Selection
        If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) And Len(rCell.Value) > 0 Then
            iHours = rCell.Value \ 100
            iMins = rCell.Value Mod 100
            rCell.Value = (iHours + iMins / 60) / 24
            rCell.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter this Macro as Module with the Sheet.
- Enter the Time as Number shown in the Screen Shot.
- Select the Data Range & Run the Macro.

*You get the desire results as shown in the Screen Shot.*