# Excel 2016 how do i enter & add time (mm:ss)

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I want to enter a length of time in minutes & seconds only into cells, and then add them together. I need to do this for time played in sports statistical reporting.

I enter the time in minutes and secs (ex: 90:00 for 90 minutes) for each player, for each game. Then, I need to sum these cells at the bottom of the page.

I consider myself computer-literate, but cannot for the life of me get anything to work. HELP!

Comment: What have you tried? What does the input look like? You can typically just add/subtract times.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad second result on google !

Comment: Do you want the sum displayed in the same format or in *hh:mm:ss* ??

Comment: You won't be able to enter minutes in that way into a cell formatted as `mm:ss`.  Excel stores time as fraction of a day, so 90 minutes is actually .0625.

Comment: You could enter the values you want into the cells and then convert those values to times in a helper cell or during your summing.

Comment: I want to enter 90 minutes to show as 90:00, or 75 minutes and 33 seconds as 75:33, 102 minutes and 54 secs as 102:54..then sum the column to report as 268:27...how do I format the data in cells??????

Comment: Sorry, just seeing your comment.  @fightingterp, you will always see the comments to your questions, but the rest of us will not unless you put `@` and our name in the comment.  See https://superuser.com/questions/1337026/converting-number-into-time-in-same-cell-in-excel/1337190#1337190 for a possibly way that could work for you.

Comment: By "see the comments", I meant "be notified of comments".

Answer (score 0):

For this EXACT (pretty much) need:  displaying minutes:seconds, and the only math you are doing is to sum the entries, you may take advantage of the fact that minutes are ALSO kept in batches of 60, like seconds are and use this format:

When you enter "90:00" (or even "90:"), Excel will record it internally as 90 hours past whichever of Excel's date starting dates you use. So, say, "1/3/1900  6:00:00 PM" is what Excel thinks. But it will display "90:00" as desired.

And it will do the summing as you wish as well. It is happy to add date entries (as it sees them) for you and also happy to display them as hours and minutes after the chosen starting date system. So the sum is "1/11/1900  4:27:00 AM" to Excel, but displays as "268:27" as you desire.

So your goals are achieved (minor pun attempt, making an assumption from the times given). Who cares if Excel thinks it is something else?

Except... important... it will limit the math uses you can make of the data and sums to more or less this.

(If you add needs later, you can, of course, use TEXT() and this format string to draw out the viewed data and sums, parse that with LEFT() and RIGHT() and doing the appropriate math on the results to give decimal values that can be operated on. And then format those results as needed.)

Answer (score -1):

See this image for a possible solution:
[image]